# Schengen visa : Can I use all of my 90 days visa validity?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, filipino-citizens, visa-expiration, schengen-visas

I am from Philippines. I applied for tourist visa in Italian Embassy. I will be an AIESEC volunteer. The duration of the program is 6 weeks. Is it possible for me to stay for another 6 weeks or so to explore and visit places?

Comment: Why do you think it's not allowed?

Comment: This appears to be 'post-submission anxiety'. Wait until you get your visa back from the VFS and see what it says.

Comment: Further to @GayotFow's comment: your visa may limit your duration of stay to a period shorter than 90 days.  You may stay in the Schengen area for however many days they grant, but the number will in no case be higher than 90.